# Creating a curve from selected edge and extruding?

Tags: extrude

I'm trying to make a cupboard, and I stumbled upon a problem (I'm a total beginner). I want to convert the edges shown in the picture to curves, bend them a little, and convert back to edge (in order to extrude the whole thing). I created the shown shape using the **Knife tool**. The reason is I'm trying to recreate a cupboard that has an negatively extruded design in a "smooth fashion" (see pic, kinda hard to explain). I'd really appreciate some help or a link to a youtube tutorial, I can't seem to find an answer to that. 
[image]

Comment: Did you try "convert to curve"? Here is a short tutorial that might help: https://youtu.be/8Iv6jfyY0aM

Comment: I already seen this video, but apparently you can convert only an Object to a curve, and not just selected edges. I tried copying that selected face, separating it, and converted it to a curve, but for some reason the curve has no handles and I can't edit it :(

Comment: When you first convert a mesh to a curve, it's a simple Poly type. To get your control handles.. in Edit Mode,  Header > Curve  menu > Set Spline Type > probably 'Bezier', then 'V' set the vertex types. 'Free' to begin with, will leave the verts where they are and give you handles.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make the drawers separate meshes? It's more logical and it will facilitate your work. Also, rather than converting curve to mesh, you should just draw the 3D profile with edge loops, then extrude, then bevel, etc...

[image]